# How to send a variable from the mainWindow to a childWindow in Electron JS?

Tags: javascript, electron, desktop-application

I'm opening a child window, with it's own HTML and JavaScript.
I want to send a property from the MainWindow javascript, an ID. to the childWindow.

The child window is a "settings" window, when done you hit Apply. I then want it to return me some HTML
information (a search input value) and the ID I originally sent to it.

Them being both renderer processes, a mainWindow and a childWindow.
How do I accomplish this?

Comment: renderer1 <-> main <-> renderer2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two windows cannot communicate directly, but you can send Informatopn via your `main.js` using `ipcRenderer`

FirstWindow:

```
const {ipcRenderer} = require('electron');
ipcRenderer.send('eventA', {SomeData});
```

main.js:

```
const {ipcMain} = require('electron');
ipcMain.on('eventA', (event, arg) => {
    secondWindow.webContents.send('EventA', arg);
});
ipcMain.on('eventB', (event, arg) => {
    firstWindow.webContents.send('EventB', arg);
});
```

child WIndow:

```
const {ipcRenderer} = require('electron');
ipcRenderer.on('EventA', (event, message) => {
    ipcRenderer.send('EventB', {someotherData});
});
```

This Way `{someData}` reaches your child window, and can be sent back the same way.