# What is the best way to pass arguments subwindow in electronjs prject

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

How can pass argument customer_ID while opening new sub window in electron appication

i have tried with modal.loadFile(`${__dirname}/pages/Company/login.html?id=1234`)
but getting error
electron: Failed to load URL: file:///Users/excelgraphics/Documents/Regular%20Jobs/OT/Aux%20service/Aux%20Services/pages/newService.html%3Fid=1234 with error: ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

```js
const popupLogin = (htmlFile, parentWindow, width, height) => {
    let modal = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 600,
        height: 500,
        modal: true,
        resizable: false,
        icon: path.join(__dirname + '/public/auxwall/logos/favicon.png'),
        parent: MainWindow,
        frame: false,
        webPreferences: {
            preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js'),
            contextIsolation: false,
            nodeIntegration: true,

        }
    })

    modal.loadFile(`${__dirname}/pages/Company/login.html`)

    return modal;
}
```

and i try to do this [How to send a variable from the mainWindow to a childWindow in Electron JS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64536788/how-to-send-a-variable-from-the-mainwindow-to-a-childwindow-in-electron-js)

but modal window can't access message from main process

can anyone help me to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rembering that your modal is just a window without a frame, data can be passed back and forth by using [Inter-Process Communication](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/ipc).

To begin securing you Electron app you should really read up on [Context Isolation](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/context-isolation).

To pass the `id` to the newly created window, use the [{window}.webContents.send](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/web-contents#contentssendchannel-args) method.

Immediately after loading the `login.html` page, send the `id` to the window.

In your main thread script...

```js
const popupLogin = (htmlFile, parentWindow, width, height) => {

    // Get the customers id from whatever source necessary.
    let id = 99;

    // Create the window.
    let modal = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 600,
        height: 500,
        modal: true,
        resizable: false,
        icon: path.join(__dirname + 
 '/public/auxwall/logos/favicon.png'),
        parent: MainWindow,
        frame: false,
        show: false, // Hide possible flash and DOM update(s).
        webPreferences: {
            preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js'),
            contextIsolation: true, // Set to true
            nodeIntegration: true,  // Node integration (removed in Electron v12)
        }
    })

    // Load the window.
    // Note: The loadFile() method returns a promise.
    modal.loadFile(`${__dirname}/pages/Company/login.html`)
        .then(() => { modal.webContents.send('login:id', id); })
        .then(() => { modal.show(); }) // Now show the modal

    return modal;
}
```

`preload.js` (main thread)

```js
const contextBridge = require('electron').contextBridge;
const ipcRenderer = require('electron').ipcRenderer;

// White-listed channels.
const ipc = {
    'render': {
        // From render to main.
        'send': [],
        // From main to render.
        'receive': [
            'login:id'
        ],
        // From render to main and back again.
        'sendReceive': []
    }
};

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld(
    // Allowed 'ipcRenderer' methods.
    'ipcRender', {
        send: (channel, args) => {
            let validChannels = ipc.render.send;
            if (validChannels.includes(channel)) {
                ipcRenderer.send(channel, args);
            }
        },
        receive: (channel, listener) => {
            let validChannels = ipc.render.receive;
            if (validChannels.includes(channel)) {
                // Deliberately strip event as it includes `sender`
                ipcRenderer.on(channel, (event, ...args) => listener(...args));
            }
        },
        invoke: (channel, args) => {
            let validChannels = ipc.render.sendReceive;
            if (validChannels.includes(channel)) {
                return ipcRenderer.invoke(channel, args);
            }
        }
    }
);
```

`login.html` (render thread)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Title</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
        <script type="module" src="login.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        ....
    </body>
</html>
```

`login.js` (render thread)

```js
(function() => {
        window.ipcRender.receive('login:id', (event, id) => { customerId(id); });
})();

function customerId(id) {
   console.log(id);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!

My application not using any external website API, do you think is good to enable context isolation? because my some scripts not running when i set true context isolation

Comment: You can get away with setting `contextIsolation: false` but it does reduce the recommended security of your Electron app. Even if you are not loading external websites or using their API's, a malicious user may try and break your app via your UI form fields or DevTools (if accessible). Whilst this may not be a concern, you need to be confident that damage won't occur via any cross-context use. The`contextIsolation:` setting is `true` by default so if you want (and have time) toggle between `true` and `false` and fix any issues 1 by 1. If it is **only you** using your app then no problem...

Comment: Brother, Can you help me to solve this issue... question link is below https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71265088/cannot-find-module-sqlite3-after-build-exe-with-electron-builder